# Flexbox container for dynamic content

Tags: flexbox

I am working on a single page template that will be used by a proprietary CMS. It is basically a header, 3 columns in majority of page, and a footer. In the middle column the CMS will inject content into it. The content can be of varying length.

I need the footer to not be fixed, so that everything resizes dynamically if the content is larger than the container's initial vh. How do I handle this?

```html
<!doctype html>
<header>
<style type="text/css">
 html, body {
  margin: 0;
 }

 #header {
  display: flex;
  background: #000000;
  height: 10vh;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
 }

 #header-left {
  background: red;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
 }

 #header-right {
  background: green;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  align-content: flex-end;
 }

 #content-container {
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  background: #cccccc;
  height: 80vh;
  justify-content: space-between;
 }

 #sidebar-left {
  background: purple;
  flex-basis: 20%;
 }

 #sidebar-right {
  background: yellow;
  flex-basis: 15%;
 }

 #content {
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  flex-basis: 65%;
  flex-grow: 
 }

 #footer {
  display: flex;
  background: white;
  height: 60px;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
 }

 #footer-left {
  background: pink;
  flex-basis: 50%;
 }

 #footer-right {
  background: orange;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  align-content: flex-end;
 }

</style>
</header>
<body>
<div id="header">
 <div id="header-left">
  HEADER-LEFT HERE
 </div>
 <div id="header-right">
  HEADER-RIGHT HERE
 </div>
</div>
<div id="content-container">
 <div id="sidebar-left">
  SIDEBAR-LEFT
 </div>
 <div id="content">
  CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum 
 </div>
 <div id="sidebar-right">
  SIDEBAR-RIGHT
 </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
 <div id="footer-left">
  FOOTER-LEFT
 </div>
 <div id="footer-right">
  FOOTER-RIGHT
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change the `height: 80vh` to `min-height: 80vh`;

```html
<!doctype html>
<header>
<style type="text/css">
 html, body {
  margin: 0;
 }

 #header {
  display: flex;
  background: #000000;
  height: 10vh;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
 }

 #header-left {
  background: red;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
 }

 #header-right {
  background: green;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  align-content: flex-end;
 }

 #content-container {
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  background: #cccccc;
  min-height: 80vh;
  justify-content: space-between;
 }

 #sidebar-left {
  background: purple;
  flex-basis: 20%;
 }

 #sidebar-right {
  background: yellow;
  flex-basis: 15%;
 }

 #content {
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  flex-basis: 65%;
  flex-grow: 
 }

 #footer {
  display: flex;
  background: white;
  height: 60px;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
 }

 #footer-left {
  background: pink;
  flex-basis: 50%;
 }

 #footer-right {
  background: orange;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  align-content: flex-end;
 }

</style>
</header>
<body>
<div id="header">
 <div id="header-left">
  HEADER-LEFT HERE
 </div>
 <div id="header-right">
  HEADER-RIGHT HERE
 </div>
</div>
<div id="content-container">
 <div id="sidebar-left">
  SIDEBAR-LEFT
 </div>
 <div id="content">
  CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum CONTENT lorum ipsum lorum ipsum 
 </div>
 <div id="sidebar-right">
  SIDEBAR-RIGHT
 </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
 <div id="footer-left">
  FOOTER-LEFT
 </div>
 <div id="footer-right">
  FOOTER-RIGHT
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```